# safe csv.file with datetime.now() as name

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime, export

I want to save a dataframe as a .csv and the name of the .csv should be

> datetime.now()

when it is stored. How can I do this?

I tried

```
werte_df.to_csv(r'C:\Masterarbeit\werte_df{0}.csv', sep=',')
```

and hoped that the 0 will be changeable, however it does not change.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) to format a string.

Example on the Python interpreter:

```
>>> 'C:\Masterarbeit\werte_df{}.csv'.format(datetime.now())
'C:\\Masterarbeit\\werte_df2021-08-24 18:04:47.685095.csv'
```

Edit: example with [f-string](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#tut-f-strings):

```
>>> f'C:\Masterarbeit\werte_df{datetime.now()}.csv'
'C:\\Masterarbeit\\werte_df2021-08-25 14:03:57.648634.csv'
```

Comment: Colons (`:`) won't work in a filename, at least on some OS. You might want to include a call to `strftime`. Also, we have f-strings, to avoid the cumbersome .format